# How to remove a specific element from a List in scala?

Tags: list, scala

Suppose

```
Val L = List(“apple”, “d”, “ass1”, “110mac”)
```

How to remove any contents appear in the second and third element from the list?

Like anything inside The second and third elements will always be removed.

Comment: List is a data structure for immutable list. In your case, use ListBuffer, and do `l.remove(1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the `List` but you can create a new one using parts of the old:

```
val list = List(“apple”, “d”, “ass1”, “110mac”)

val list2 = list.take(1) ++ list.drop(3)
```

Note that this is robust to the case where the list has fewer than 4 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip elements with index and then remove elements at the indexes you want, like below:

```
val fruitList = List("apple", "orange", "banana", "apricot", "blueberry", "cherry")
val removeSet = Set(2,3) // This set contains indexes of fruits which should be removed from fruitList
val resultList = fruitList.zipWithIndex //zip fruits with indexes to get List[(fruit, index)]
.filter(x => !(removeSet.contains(x._2))) // filter List[(fruit, index)] to remove fruits present at indexes contained in removeSet
.map(_._1) // map List[(fruit, index)] to List[fruit]
println(resultList) // prints List(apple, orange, blueberry, cherry)
```

Comment: It would be better to call `iterator` before the `zip` and add a `toList` at the end, so this is more efficient. Also, it would be better to use `.collect { case (x, idx) if (!removeSet.contains(idx)) => x }` instead of `filter` + `map`.